# Why is this function using dicts slower than "if's"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I dont understand why this function using dicts is slower than "if's", can someone explain me why/and give me a faster and more pythonic way than "`if` x 3" (which will get worse if more comparisons are needed in the long run)?

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("""
... conv_table = {'USEWR': 'USNYC',
...               'PAMIT': 'PACTB',
...               'NLMSV': 'NLRTM'}
... def fn(code: str):
...     # conversion for those values:
...     return conv_table.get(code, code)
... fn('USEWR')
... fn('PAMIT')
... fn('NLMSV')
... fn('XYZ')
... """)
0.6174538989998837
```

And the one, faster but using "`if`'s":

```
timeit.timeit("""
... def fn(code: str):
...     if code == 'USEWR':
...         return 'USNYC'
...     if code == 'PAMIT':
...         return 'PACTB'
...     if code == 'NLMSV':
...         return 'NLRTM'
...     return code
... fn('USEWR')
... fn('PAMIT')
... fn('NLMSV')
... fn('XYZ')
... """)
0.5126422860003004
```

Comment: Your using a method call in the dict example. Method calls are expensive. So calling get to return the value or a default is a costly operation compared to just using if statements to compare

Comment: If the dict is constant then it should be passed to timeit as part of the `setup` so that you don't time its creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris Doyle pointed out, you're doing 4 more functions calls by calling `.get()` in your `fn` function. This would be a better comparison:

```py
timeit.timeit("""
conv_table = {'USEWR': 'USNYC',
              'PAMIT': 'PACTB',
              'NLMSV': 'NLRTM'}
conv_table.get('USEWR', 'USEWR')
conv_table.get('PAMIT', 'PAMIT')
conv_table.get('NLMSV', 'NLMSV')
conv_table.get('XYZ', 'XYZ')
""")
# 0.31812165299925255

timeit.timeit("""
def fn(code: str):
    if code == 'USEWR':
        return 'USNYC'
    if code == 'PAMIT':
        return 'PACTB'
    if code == 'NLMSV':
        return 'NLRTM'
    return code
fn('USEWR')
fn('PAMIT')
fn('NLMSV')
fn('XYZ')
""")
# 0.49393055400287267
```

Comment: **Method calls are expensive.** . This is the most important lesson today!

Comment: @OlivierPons you can still have a default returned by doing something like `return conv_table[locode] if locode in conv_table else locode`

Comment: No offense, but what is the difference with `conv_table.get(locode, locode)`

Comment: The difference is `get` is a method call which is expensive, using `in` to check if the values in the dict means if it is you return the value if its not you return the original key